# jquery .click() not functioning after Ajax 403 response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some ajax that's returning a 403 error message but when it does, the click() function that was associated with the ajax call no longer works.  I don't append or add any HTML before or after the ajax call, and if the ajax doesn't receive a 403 error, there are no problems.  It's just simply if I receive a 403 error from the ajax POST, then the click() breaks.  How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```js
$( "#add_comment" ).on('click', null, function() {
  
  var data = {token:"{{ Session::token() }}", comment:$('#game_comment_form form textarea').val() };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/game/comment/{{$game->id}}',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      alert("Success");
    },
    statusCode: {
      403: function() {
        alert( "Forbidden" );
      }
    },
    error: function(e){
      alert("Error");
      console.log(e);
    }

  });

  return false;

});
```

Comment: Don't know the inner workings of the ajax function from jQuery, but the 403 section has a function attached that returns `false` the other returns don't. Maybe that makes the difference.

Comment: There's technically a return false; at the end of the whole statement so everything eventually returns false regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was completely overlooking the fact that I manually disable the input button and just simply forgot to re-enable it after the 403.  I was going to delete this but hopefully someone else possibly realizes their simple mistake as I have and this helps them out.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try $.post(); method ?

like this...

```
$.post('/game/comment/{{$game->id}}',data,function(data){
  alert("Success");
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // called on success
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // called on failure
}).always(function() {
    // called in both cases 
});
```